# How to use "PASCAL Annotation" files to train SVM with C++

Tags: c++, opencv, annotations, pascal

I need to test my selfwritten person detector using Hog Descriptor (Dalal paper) on a Scientific dataset (INRIA person dataset). I have thousands of pos and neg Images in my Folder to train a Support Vector Machine (SVM). However to label the Images as positive (1.0) or negative (-1.0) I need to read the information from a text file that is provided with the dataset in a so called "PASCAL Annotation" format.

My problem is that I don't know how to read this format efficiently. I'm using C++ and OpenCV. Does anyone know how to do this efficiently? Are there already code snippets for C++?

In the end I need a loop that goes through a file "Annotations.lst" where all the picture filenames are listed. The program loads the picture and the corresponding annotation file (picturename.txt) to see if this picture belongs to a positive or negative training data (or later when actually detecting: if the tested picture belongs to a detected person or not)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best implementation but works fine, hope it becomes useful even today! You will need filesystem library in order to work with files.

```
string line,value; //Line stores lines of the file and value stores characters of the line
int i=0; //Iterate through lines
int j=0; //Iterate through characters
int n=0; //Iterate through ,()-...
char v; //Stores variable value as a char to be able to make comparisions easily

vector <Rect> anotations; //Stores rectangles for each image
vector <int> bbValues; //Bounding box values (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)

fs::path anotationsFolder = "THE FOLDER PATH OF ANOTATIONS"; //Path of anotations folder
fs::path anotationsParsedFolder = "THE FOLDER PATH TO STORE PARSED ANOTATIONS"; //Path to store new anotations

fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(anotationsFolder); //Iteradores of files
fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;

cout<<"Loading anotations from "<<anotationsFolder<<endl;

while((it != endit)) //Until end of folder
{
    if((fs::is_regular_file(*it))) //Good practice
    {
        fs::path imagePath(it->path()); //Complete path of the image

        cout<<"Reading anotations from"<<it->path().filename()<<endl;

        ifstream inputFile; //Declare input file with image path
        inputFile.open(imagePath.string().data(), std::ios_base::in);

        i=0;
        while (! inputFile.eof() ){ //Until end of file

            getline (inputFile,line);//Get lines one by one

            if ((i>=17) && ((i-17)%7==0)){ //In lines numer 17,24,31,38...where bounding boxes coordinates are

                j=69;
                v=line[j]; //Start from character num 69 corresponding to first value of Xmin

                while (j<line.size()){ //Until end of line

                    if (v=='(' || v==',' || v==')' || v==' ' || v=='-'){ //if true, push back acumulated value unless previous value wasn't a symbol also
                        if (n==0){
                            bbValues.push_back(stoi(value)); //stoi converts string in to integer ("567"->567) 
                            value.clear();
                        }
                        n++;
                    }
                    else{
                        value+=v; //Append new number
                        n=0;//Reset in order to know that a number has been read
                    }
                    j++;
                    v=line[j];//Read next character
                }
                Rect rect(bbValues[0],bbValues[1],bbValues[2]-bbValues[0],bbValues[3]-bbValues[1]); //Build a rectangle rect(xmin,ymin,xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin)
                anotations.push_back(rect);
                bbValues.clear();
            }
            i++;//Next line
        }
        inputFile.close();            

        cout<<"Writing..."<<endl;

        //Save the anotations to a file
        ofstream outputFile; //Declare file
        fs::path outputPath(anotationsParsedFolder / it->path().filename());// Complete path of the file
        outputFile.open(outputPath.string().data(), ios_base::trunc);

        // Store anotations as x y width heigth
        for (int i=0; i<anotations.size(); i++){
            outputFile<<anotations[i].x<<" ";
            outputFile<<anotations[i].y<<" ";
            outputFile<<anotations[i].width<<" ";
            outputFile<<anotations[i].height<<endl;
        }
        anotations.clear();
        outputFile.close();
    }
    ++it;//Next file in anotations folder
}
```